# Read data.table in chunks and include the first line as the header

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to read a large CSV file in chunks, so that for each chunk we read the first line to determine the column names, and read rows N+1 through N+n from the file to form the data portion of the `data.table`. I have experimented with parameters `nrows`, `skip` and `header` of the `fread` command and though I can read in chunks, I haven't been able to use the first line as the header. Is there a way to do this?

Also, is there way for `fread` not to look past row N+n in the file, to speed things up? (Is it doing this by default?)

One more point: The documentation says `fread` starts on row `skip+1` but it actually seem to start reading on row `skip`.

Comment: I did not spot an option in `fread`, too. But of course you can always augment the function in the veins of `csv <- "a b\n1 2\n3 4"; fread_ <- function(csv, sep = " ", ...) setNames(fread(csv, sep = sep, ...), unlist(read.table(text = csv, sep = sep, nrows = 1, stringsAsFactors = F))); fread_(csv, skip = 2, nrow = 1)`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to read the file in chunks in the first place, but I recommend doing basically what @lukeA recommended if you insist on doing so: set `header=F` and wrap `fread` in `setnames`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico, the file is too big for my memory constraints, that is why I have to read it in chunks. The code needs to run on a cluster with hard limits on virtual memory size. If the job requests more than 64GB of (virtual) memory, it gets killed.